# Is there a canonical Python reference mutation question?

Tags: discussion, canonical

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39822219/781965) came up on my review queue, and I'm wondering if there's a canonical version of these "X variable (or name or whatever they're called in Python) gets mutated by changing a different reference to it" questions.

These kinds of questions spring up fairly frequently for other languages, so I thought maybe there was a canonical dupe question for Python.

Comment: Have a look in http://sopython.com/canon/

Comment: @jonrsharpe handy resource, but not for closing as a duplicate :) if I come across python questions that look common though, I'll try to remember to link to that if it seems appropriate.

Comment: No, don't link to it - use it to find the dupes! They're all links to canonical questions here on SO.

Comment: If you have no idea then press the Skip button.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh! I clicked through but didn't see the link through to the question - thanks :)

Comment: @HansPassant that's exactly what I did in this case (and many others), but it's always good to try to learn more.

Comment: Apparently not (from looking at the canon), so please create one. Tagged both Python and numpy, I recommend. I suggest we want to illustrate with both a pure Python example (e.g. list/object), and a numpy array one.

Comment: @smci I've never written a line of Python in my life, so I'm probably not best equipped to ask it, much as I might like the reputation :P feel free to "steal" my thunder on this one (and don't forget to post an answer here if you do!).